# Test if checkboxes in a table are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have this huge(1334 pages) table. My problem: how can I test all created checkboxes and determine if they're "checked"? May be should I input "checkbox" in another way?
This is part of code from .ftl file. It's problem for me to understand all coded.

```
    [#list result.content as item]
    [#assign publicationType = (item.esbPublicationType)?default("не опубликован") /]
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            ${(item.createdTime.time?string("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))?default("не известно")}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${(item.visit.branchOffice.name)?default("не известно")}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="[#if publicationType == "ERROR"]alert round label[/#if] publication-info" visit_id="${item.visit.id}">
            ${publicationType}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            [#--<a href="#" class="tiny round  visit-info" visit_id="${item.visit.id}">Просмотр визита</a>--]
            <a href="[@spring.url "/visit/publicate?id=" + item.visit.id/]"
               target="_blank" class="tiny round  publicate" visit_id="${item.id}">Опубликовать</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
[/#list]

[#list result.content as item]
    [#assign publicationType = (item.esbPublicationType)?default("не опубликован") /]
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            ${(item.createdTime.time?string("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))?default("не известно")}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${(item.visit.branchOffice.name)?default("не известно")}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="[#if publicationType == "ERROR"]alert round label[/#if] publication-info" visit_id="${item.visit.id}">
            ${publicationType}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            [#--<a href="#" class="tiny round  visit-info" visit_id="${item.visit.id}">Просмотр визита</a>--]
            <a href="[@spring.url "/visit/publicate?id=" + item.visit.id/]"
               target="_blank" class="tiny round  publicate" visit_id="${item.id}">Опубликовать</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
[/#list]
```

I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function (){
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("checkbox");
    for(i=0; i < checkbox.length; i++)
    {
        if(checkbox[i].checked){
        console.log("Work");
    }else{
        alert("Ни один из визитов не выбран");
    }
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Use `:checked` for input checkboxes...

Comment: Please elaborate _how can I check all created checkboxes for boolean value "checked"?_ If you want to check all them you can use `$(':checkbox').prop('checked', true)`

Comment: Do you want to *set* all the checkboxes to checked/unchecked, or do you want to *test* if they are all checked?

Comment: I want to test it. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

To check all checkboxes, use `$(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);`

```
<p><input type="checkbox" /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" /></p> // all unchecked

// on document ready (or whenever you need)
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);

// Chekboxes are now all checked
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/7QLEj/

If you'd like to determine if a checkbox is checked, use `$('selector').prop("checked")`.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" checked /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" checked /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" checked /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" checked /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" checked /></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" /></p>

// on document ready (or whenever you need)
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop("checked"))
        $(this).parent().append("<span>This is checked</span>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/7B6t7/

Comment: My mistake that my english is so bad, but i need to test this boolean value, not to set. Thank you.

Comment: It's realy what i needed. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Happy to help! Please mark the question as correct if it is so.

Comment: And can we replace '.checkbox' by "attr_name"??

Comment: yes, `:checkbox` is just a CSS selector- you can use `input[type=checkbox]`, `.my-checkbox`, `#thisCheckbox`, etc. Any valid CSS selector will work. Note this solution uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in order to 'check' all checkbox inside the table :

```
 $(function () {

    $("table [type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);
 });
```

For testing whether it is checked or not :

```
if ($("table [type=checkbox]").attr("checked")==true){
    alert("checked");   
}else{
   alert("not checked");       
}
```

I could find a small mistake in your code , please close the input tag properly

```
    <td>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/></p>
    </td>
```